# Solve Euler Lagrange equation of motion DSolve

Tags: differential-equations, physics

I'm trying to find Euler Lagrange equation of motion.
then DSolve the equation for list of variable x1,x2,x3,x4

Here is my code:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
Needs["VariationalMethods`"]
n = 3; 
ue[x_, t_, k_, n_] := (1/2)*Sum[Subscript[k, j]*(Subscript[x, j - 1][t] - Subscript[x, j][t])^2, {j, 1, n + 1}]; 
te[x_, t_, n_] := (1/2)*m*Sum[Derivative[1][Subscript[x, j]][t]^2, {j, 1, n}]; 
lg[x_, t_, k_, n_] := te[x, t, n] - ue[x, t, k, n]; 

Expand[EulerEquations[lg[x, t, k, n], Subscript[x, j][t], t]]
DSolve[%, Subscript[x, j][t], x]
```

Here is picture of my code

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Corrected and runnable code:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
Needs["VariationalMethods`"]
n = 3;
ue[x_, t_, k_, n_] := (1/2)* Sum[k[j]*(x[j][t] - x[Mod[j + 1, n, 1]][t])^2, {j, 1, n}];
te[x_, t_, n_] := (1/2)*m*Sum[Derivative[1][x[j]][t]^2, {j, 1, n}];
lg[x_, t_, k_, n_] := te[x, t, n] - ue[x, t, k, n];
eq = Expand[
   EulerEquations[lg[x, t, k, n], Table[x[j][t], {j, 1, n}], t]
   ];
DSolve[eq, Table[x[j][t], {j, 1, n}], t]
```

Changes made:

- Although it was not the source of the problem, I removed `Subscript`: It is nasty to read in input form and it does not do what you expect.
- You have to take care that your indices do not run out of bounds; this is why I shortened the sum and why I use `Mod` in the definition of `ue`.
- You have to submit *all* unknown functions as second argument to `EulerEquations` which is what I used `Table` for.
- The above holds true also dor `DSolve`. Moreover, the third argument of `DSolve` has to be from the domain of the differential equations; in this case, it has to be `t`, not `x`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir, God Bless You.

Comment: You're welcome.